# How can I kill all yarn applications which are in "ACCEPTED" state

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

How can I kill all yarn applications which are in "ACCEPTED" state.
I have more than 1K processes in accepted state, how can I kill them all.
Currently I am using this shell script to kill all accepted jobs:

```
for app in `yarn application -list | awk '$6 == "ACCEPTED" { print $1 }'`; do yarn application -kill  "$app";  done
```

is there any better way to do so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK creating small script is the right way for now and same you are already did. Since "-Appstates" option only works with -list subcommand, so there is no other inbuilt shell option available to do that. you can do research in API side and see if you can create a sample java program to achieve this (but not sure).